# Removendo a classe CSS de acordo com a resolução da tela

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando remover uma classe CSS pelo JavaScript quando a tela diminui

Só que o evento que estou usando é o `scroll`, que é pra rolagem de mouse. Aí toda vez q a tela diminui preciso rolar o mouse para a função funcionar.

Alguém sabe um evento próprio para resolução no JavaScript?

```js
jQuery(function () {
                
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    
      if (jQuery(this).width() < 1200) {        
         $("#divtexto").removeClass("col-6");      
         $("#textMaratona").removeClass("col-6");       
      }else{       
         $("#divtexto").addClass("col-6");     
         $("#textMaratona").addClass("col-6");   
     } 
        
   });
       
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deve utilizar o evento [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) para isso. Veja a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) do *handler* jQuery.

Assim:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(this).width() < 1200) {
      $('#example').removeClass('custom');
    } else {
      $('#example').addClass('custom');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#example.custom {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">Olá, mundo!</div>
```

Comment: vlw msm kara.. deu certo aqui kkkk muit obg...

Answer (score 1):

Poderia usar os dois eventos ao mesmo tempo usando o método [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
```

Basta colocar os eventos separados por um espaço, como mostrado acima.

**Mas** não faz muito sentido usar o evento `scroll`, já que ele não tem nada a ver com a largura da janela. Use apenas o evento `resize`:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
```

E você pode ainda simplificar o código usando um ternário, se for só pra fazer isso, adicionando/removendo a classe dos dois elementos ao mesmo tempo:

```
$(function () {
   $(window).on("resize", function () {
      $("#divtexto, #textMaratona")
      [(jQuery(this).width() < 1200 ? "remove" : "add") + "Class"]
      ("col-6");      
   });
});
```

> Pra quê usar `JQuery` se você pode usar o alias `$`? Economiza uns
>   bytes de código.

Comment: testei dessa forma tambem.. e deu certo.. vlw kara..

Comment: Marque uma das respostas com ✔.